# In Celery tasks, do retry_backoff and retry_backoff_max affect the manual self.retry() calls?

Tags: celery, celery-task

So according to the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.default_retry_delay), `default_retry_delay`specifies the time in seconds before a retry of the task should be executed. I just want to be sure that this only affects the manually called `self.retry()`calls and not the autoretries triggered by Celery when the task encounters predefined exceptions.

Likewise, I want to know if `retry_backoff` and `retry_backoff_max`only affect the autoretries and not the manual `self.retry()`.

Finally, what happens when all of these are set?

Answer (score 2):

That answer may change depending on the version of Celery that is used. However, as far as I have checked with the source code of versions [v4.3.1](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/v4.3.1/celery/app/base.py#L476), [v4.4.7](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/v4.4.7/celery/app/autoretry.py#L45) and [v5.0.0](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/v5.0.0/celery/app/autoretry.py#L44), `retry_backoff` and `retry_backoff_max` only affect the auto-retry. If `autoretry_for` is not set as `True` (or a True value such as positive integers), then the backoff parameters is not used.

As it can be seen from the implementation, when a True value is set to `autoretry_for`, Celery uses `retry_backoff`, `retry_backoff_max`, and `retry_jitter` arguments in order to compute the `countdown` of the next retry, before calling `.retry` method. Thus, these `retry_xx` arguments are not directly used by the `.retry` method; however, they affect the value of `countdown`. Thus, they are only used in the `auto_retry`.

When the `countdown` is explicity defined or computed via `autoretry`, then the value of `default_retry_delay` is ignored, as it can be seen in [the implementation of v5.0.0](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/v5.0.0/celery/app/task.py#L687). The same is valid when `eta` is set. Thus, to be able to use `default_retry_delay`, `countdown`, and `eta` should not be set. Additionally, `autoretry_for` should not be set or it should be set with a `False` value.

Another approach to use `default_retry_delay` and `autoretry` at the same time would be to define autoretry and retry variables; but for manual retry calls, set the `eta` and `countdown` to `None` explicitly. One example:

```py
@app.task(bind=True, default_retry_delay=360, autoretry_for=[ExternalApiError], max_retries=5, retry_backoff=1800, retry_backoff_max=8 * 3600, retry_jitter=False)
def my_task(self, data):
   try:
      ... # some code here that may raise ExternalApiError
   except SomeOtherError:
      try:
         self.retry(countdown=None, eta=None)
      except self.MaxRetriesExceededError:
         ... # when maximum number of retries has been exceeded.
```

If you want to use backoff parameters with manual retry calls, it can be implemented by using the method  `get_exponential_backoff_interval` of Celery. One example could be this:

```py
from celery.utils.time import get_exponential_backoff_interval

@app.task(bind=True, max_retries=5)
def my_task(self, data):
   try:
      ... # some code here that may raise ExternalApiError
   except SomeOtherError:
      try:
         retry_backoff = True
         retry_backoff_max = 5
         retry_jitter = True
         countdown = get_exponential_backoff_interval(
             factor=retry_backoff,
             retries=self.request.retries,
             maximum=retry_backoff_max,
             full_jitter=retry_jitter)
         )
         self.retry(countdown=countdown)
      except self.MaxRetriesExceededError:
         ... # when maximum number of retries has been exceeded.
```